# Swift: Use of unresolved Identifier. Target Membership

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Swift script below relating to Sleep Analysis.

**Error:**

> View Controller has no member 'updateTime'.

I tried adding this target using file inspector and adding it to target membership, but the target itself won't show up, which is beyond weird. Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

PS: Another error message not saying that 'error' is an unresolved identifier for an `if != nil` statement keeps popping up. Any help here, would also be highly appreciated.

```
import UIKit
import HealthKit

    let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var displayTimeLabel: UILabel!

    var startTime = TimeInterval()
    var timer:Timer = Timer()
    var endTime: NSDate!
    var alarmTime: NSDate!

    func saveSleepAnalysis() {

        //1. startTime(alarmTime) and endTime are NSDate Objects//
        if let sleepType = HKObjectType.categoryType(forIdentifier: HKCategoryTypeIdentifier.sleepAnalysis) {
            //we create a new object that we want to add into our Health app(This is our INBED object)//
            let object1 = HKCategorySample(type:sleepType, value: HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysis.inBed.rawValue, start: self.alarmTime as Date, end: self.endTime as Date)
            // Time to save the object//
            healthStore.save(object1, withCompletion: { (success, errpr) -> Void in

            if error != nil
                {
                    return
                }

                if success {
                    print("My new data was saved in HealthKit")

                } else {
                    //something happened again//
                }
            })
            //This our ASLEEP object//
            let object2 = HKCategorySample(type:sleepType, value: HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysis.asleep.rawValue, start: self.alarmTime as Date, end: self.endTime as Date)
            //now we save our objects to our mainLibrary known as HealthStore
            healthStore.save(object2, withCompletion: { (success, error) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                        //Something went wrong//
                    return

                    if success {
                        print("My new data (2: Asleep data) was saved into HealthKit")
                    } else {
                           //something happened again//
                    }
                }
        }
    )}

        func retrieveSleepAnalysis() {
            //first, define our object type that we watn again in BOOLEAN FORMAT//
            if let sleepType = HKObjectType.categoryType(forIdentifier: HKCategoryTypeIdentifier.sleepAnalysis) {

                //use sortDescriptor to get teh recent data first: so from MostRecentData to PastData//
                let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierEndDate, ascending: false)

                //we create our query with a block completion to execute
                let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: sleepType, predicate: nil, limit:30, sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) { (query, tmpResult, error) -> Void in

                    if error != nil {
                        //something happends//
                        return
                    }
                    if let result = tmpResult {

                        //then i want the computer to do something with my data//
                        for item in result {
                            if let sample = item as? HKCategorySample {
                                let value = (sample.value == HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysis.inBed.rawValue) ? "InBed" : "Asleep"
                                print("Healthkit sleep: \(sample.startDate) \(sample.endDate) = value: \(value)")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                //finally, we execute our query: Print out our output file //
                healthStore.execute(query)
            }
        }
        func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let typestoRead = Set([
            HKObjectType.categoryType(forIdentifier: HKCategoryTypeIdentifier.sleepAnalysis)!
            ])

        let typestoShare = Set([
            HKObjectType.categoryType(forIdentifier: HKCategoryTypeIdentifier.sleepAnalysis)!
            ])
            healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: typestoShare, read: typestoRead) { (success, error) -> Void in
            if success == false {
                    NSLog(" Display not allowed")
            }
        }
    }


func updateTime() {
        let currentTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate

        //Find the difference between current time and start time.
        var elapsedTime: TimeInterval = currentTime - startTime

        //calculate the minutes in elapsed time.
        let minutes = UInt8(elapsedTime / 60.0)
        elapsedTime -= (TimeInterval(minutes) * 60)

        //calculate the seconds in elapsed time.
        let seconds = UInt8(elapsedTime)
        elapsedTime -= TimeInterval(seconds)

        //find out the fraction of milliseconds to be displayed.
        let fraction = UInt8(elapsedTime * 100)

        //add the leading zero for minutes, seconds and millseconds and store them as string constants

        let strMinutes = String(format: "%02d", minutes)
        let strSeconds = String(format: "%02d", seconds)
        let strFraction = String(format: "%02d", fraction)

        //concatenate minuets, seconds and milliseconds as assign it to the UILabel
        displayTimeLabel.text = "\(strMinutes):\(strSeconds):\(strFraction)"
    }


        func start(sender: AnyObject) {
            alarmTime = NSDate()
            if (!timer.isValid) {
                let Selector : Selector = #selector(ViewController.updateTime)
                timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: Selector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
                startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
            }

        }



        func stop(sender: AnyObject) {
            endTime = NSDate()
            saveSleepAnalysis()
            retrieveSleepAnalysis()
            timer.invalidate()
        }

        func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you might have some indentation and possible scope issues. Are you certain that function updateTime is defined in the class?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this

```
import UIKit
import HealthKit

let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var displayTimeLabel: UILabel!

    var startTime = TimeInterval()
    var timer:Timer = Timer()
    var endTime: NSDate!
    var alarmTime: NSDate!

    func saveSleepAnalysis() {

        //1. startTime(alarmTime) and endTime are NSDate Objects//
        if let sleepType = HKObjectType.categoryType(forIdentifier: HKCategoryTypeIdentifier.sleepAnalysis) {
            //we create a new object that we want to add into our Health app(This is our INBED object)//
            let object1 = HKCategorySample(type:sleepType, value: HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysis.inBed.rawValue, start: self.alarmTime as Date, end: self.endTime as Date)
            // Time to save the object//
            healthStore.save(object1, withCompletion: { (success, errpr) -> Void in

                if errpr != nil
                {
                    return
                }

                if success {
                    print("My new data was saved in HealthKit")

                } else {
                    //something happened again//
                }
            })
            //This our ASLEEP object//
            let object2 = HKCategorySample(type:sleepType, value: HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysis.asleep.rawValue, start: self.alarmTime as Date, end: self.endTime as Date)
            //now we save our objects to our mainLibrary known as HealthStore
            healthStore.save(object2, withCompletion: { (success, error) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    //Something went wrong//
                    return

                    if success {
                        print("My new data (2: Asleep data) was saved into HealthKit")
                    } else {
                        //something happened again//
                    }
                }
            }
            )}


    }

    func retrieveSleepAnalysis() {
        //first, define our object type that we watn again in BOOLEAN FORMAT//
        if let sleepType = HKObjectType.categoryType(forIdentifier: HKCategoryTypeIdentifier.sleepAnalysis) {

            //use sortDescriptor to get teh recent data first: so from MostRecentData to PastData//
            let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierEndDate, ascending: false)

            //we create our query with a block completion to execute
            let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: sleepType, predicate: nil, limit:30, sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) { (query, tmpResult, error) -> Void in

                if error != nil {
                    //something happends//
                    return
                }
                if let result = tmpResult {

                    //then i want the computer to do something with my data//
                    for item in result {
                        if let sample = item as? HKCategorySample {
                            let value = (sample.value == HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysis.inBed.rawValue) ? "InBed" : "Asleep"
                            print("Healthkit sleep: \(sample.startDate) \(sample.endDate) = value: \(value)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //finally, we execute our query: Print out our output file //
            healthStore.execute(query)
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let typestoRead = Set([
            HKObjectType.categoryType(forIdentifier: HKCategoryTypeIdentifier.sleepAnalysis)!
            ])

        let typestoShare = Set([
            HKObjectType.categoryType(forIdentifier: HKCategoryTypeIdentifier.sleepAnalysis)!
            ])
        healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: typestoShare, read: typestoRead) { (success, error) -> Void in
            if success == false {
                NSLog(" Display not allowed")
            }
        }
    }


    func updateTime() {
        let currentTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate

        //Find the difference between current time and start time.
        var elapsedTime: TimeInterval = currentTime - startTime

        //calculate the minutes in elapsed time.
        let minutes = UInt8(elapsedTime / 60.0)
        elapsedTime -= (TimeInterval(minutes) * 60)

        //calculate the seconds in elapsed time.
        let seconds = UInt8(elapsedTime)
        elapsedTime -= TimeInterval(seconds)

        //find out the fraction of milliseconds to be displayed.
        let fraction = UInt8(elapsedTime * 100)

        //add the leading zero for minutes, seconds and millseconds and store them as string constants

        let strMinutes = String(format: "%02d", minutes)
        let strSeconds = String(format: "%02d", seconds)
        let strFraction = String(format: "%02d", fraction)

        //concatenate minuets, seconds and milliseconds as assign it to the UILabel
        displayTimeLabel.text = "\(strMinutes):\(strSeconds):\(strFraction)"
    }


    func start(sender: AnyObject) {
        alarmTime = NSDate()
        if (!timer.isValid) {
            let Selector : Selector = #selector(ViewController.updateTime)
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: Selector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
        }

    }



    func stop(sender: AnyObject) {
        endTime = NSDate()
        saveSleepAnalysis()
        retrieveSleepAnalysis()
        timer.invalidate()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem with this code is in line 50: "The code after 'return' will never be executed"

Comment: line 50 of my code ? your issue was not able to refer UpdateTime and in my code I solved that issue if there is another issue please let me know as I hadn't build that code I just solved UpdateTime issue

Comment: The issue has been solved. It turned out to be a problem with the software itself, thank you for your help.